# Unable to configure Parameter Group for Neptune Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create Neptune DB with terraform, but facing the following issue.

[image]

Please find the terraform script i am using.

```
## Create Neptune DB cluster and instance
resource "aws_neptune_cluster_parameter_group" "neptune1" {
  family      = "neptune1.2"
  name        = "neptune1"
  description = "neptune cluster parameter group"

  parameter {
    name  = "neptune_enable_audit_log"
    value = 1
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }
}

resource "aws_neptune_cluster" "gh-cluster" {
  cluster_identifier                  = "gh-db"
  skip_final_snapshot                 = true
  iam_database_authentication_enabled = false
  apply_immediately                   = true
  neptune_subnet_group_name           = "${aws_neptune_subnet_group.gh-dbg.name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids              = ["${aws_security_group.sgdb.id}"]
  iam_roles                           = ["${aws_iam_role.NeptuneRole.arn}"]
}

resource "aws_neptune_cluster_instance" "gh-instance" {
  count              = 1
  cluster_identifier = "${aws_neptune_cluster.gh-cluster.id}"
  engine             = "neptune"
  instance_class     = "db.r5.large"
  apply_immediately  = true
}



resource "aws_neptune_subnet_group" "gh-dbg" {
  name       = "gh-dbg"
  subnet_ids = ["${aws_subnet.private.id}" , "${aws_subnet.public.id}"]
}
```

I think i am not adding the parameter group to the Neptune DB and i am not sure how to do that.

I have tried the following keys in the terraform instance script.

1. db_parameter_group
2. parameter_group_name

But both are throwing error - 'This argument is not expected here'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Official documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/neptune_cluster#neptune_cluster_parameter_group_name) the argument you are looking for is "neptune_cluster_parameter_group_name"

```
resource "aws_neptune_cluster" "gh-cluster" {
  cluster_identifier                   = "gh-db"
  skip_final_snapshot                  = true
  iam_database_authentication_enabled  = false
  apply_immediately                    = true
  neptune_subnet_group_name            = "${aws_neptune_subnet_group.gh-dbg.name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids               = ["${aws_security_group.sgdb.id}"]
  iam_roles                            = ["${aws_iam_role.NeptuneRole.arn}"]
  neptune_cluster_parameter_group_name = "${aws_neptune_cluster_parameter_group.neptune1.name}"
}
```